# use a makefile for processing files according two Suffix Rules

Tags: makefile

I have a docroot folder containing source files that need to built
.usp -> .so 
.htt -> .html

Currently my makefile has the following :
    .SUFFIXES: .usp .htt

```
SOURCES = $(wildcard docroot/*.usp) $(wildcard docroot/*.htt)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.usp=.so) $(SOURCES:.htt=.html)

all : ${OBJECTS}
.PHONY : all 

%.usp: %.so
    usp_compile_incl.sh -i ~/Projects/Concise-ILE/include $<

%.htt: %.html
    gpp -I~/Projects/Concise-ILE/include -C $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f docroot/*.so docroot/*.html
```

make: *** No rule to make target 'docroot/fortune.so', needed by 'all'.  Stop.

SOLUTION as per sauerburger

```
.SUFFIXES: .usp .htt

SOURCES_USP  = $(wildcard docroot/*.usp)
SOURCES_HTT = $(wildcard docroot/*.htt)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES_USP:.usp=.so) $(SOURCES_HTT:.htt=.html)

all : ${OBJECTS}
    .PHONY : all 

%.so: %.usp
    usp_compile_incl.sh -i ~/Projects/Concise-ILE/include $<

%.html: %.htt
    gpp -I~/Projects/Concise-ILE/include -C $< -o $@
```

Comment: Which rule should produce `fortune.so`?

Comment: usp_compile_incl.sh -i ~/Projects/Concise-ILE/include $<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build rules for `.so` and `.html` are the wrong way round. This should work:

```
%.so: %.usp
    usp_compile_incl.sh -i ~/Projects/Concise-ILE/include $<

%.html: %.htt
    gpp -I~/Projects/Concise-ILE/include -C $< -o $@
```

The syntax of rules is `TARGET: DEPENDENCIES`.

You should also split the sources variable

```
SOURCES_USP  = $(wildcard docroot/*.usp)
SOURCES_HTT = $(wildcard docroot/*.htt)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES_USP:.usp=.so) $(SOURCES_HTT:.htt=.html)
```

Otherwise you end up with a mixed objects list. The first replacement would also include all `*.htt` files, and the second would include all `*.ups` files.

Comment: Thankyou make is now working I knew it was something simple that I was overlooking.